# What do you call a shop or place where phones, laptops and tablets are fixed?

Tags: word-choice

What do native English speakers call a place where phones, computers, tablets, headphones are fixed. Would they call it a technician's shop? For example:

> I am going to take my phone to the technician's shop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works.  I would probably call it a *phone repair shop,* an *electronics repair shop,* a *computer repair shop,* or the like.

"Technician" by itself is not particularly specific, of course, but in the context of the sentence given in the question, it should be fairly clear what you mean.

It seems a bit more normal to refer to a shop by the function of the shop rather than the occupation of the person who keeps it.  That is, *the repair shop* rather than *the technician's shop.*  Reading that you are going to the technician's shop, I am inclined to wonder whether you mean to make reference to a specific person.  This is by no means universal, though.  For example, it's quite natural to say one is going "to the butcher's."  But that's probably because we don't much use a word like "butchery" for such a place.  I would be more inclined to speak of going "to the bakery" than "to the baker's."

For what it's worth, my English is of the northeastern US variety, with a rather stronger influence of England and Europe than most people who grew up in the northeastern US.  I would be entirely unsurprised if people from other parts of the world, or even people from my part of the world, take a different view of the question.

Comment: Is it natural to call it just "repair shop". For example: "I am taking my phone to a repair shop."

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope yes, since the object "my phone" establishes the context.  It would in fact be more natural to say that than "I am taking my phone to a phone repair shop."  If you want to use some word other than "phone" to qualify "repair shop," that would also be natural, but not necessary.

Comment: butchery is not a butcher's shop.

Comment: @Lambie Yes it is.  It's not much used in that sense in the modern language, however.  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/butchery and https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/butchery for example.

Comment: It's not used at all like. I really don't care about dictionaries in cases like this. Some writer or other might use it....but it's not used really.

Comment: @Lambie ...which was precisely my point in mentioning it.